# Calibration in the large for continuous outcomes

Tags: regression, calibration

I'm a bit confused around calibration in the large. I usually see it discussed in the context of binary outcomes, but am I correct in thinking it can also be valuable as a part of external validation for a continuous outcome?

Assuming it is still of interest, I have also seen two ways of calculating it

- The difference between the mean of the observed/actual values and the mean of the predicted values.
- As the intercept of a model of actual values regressed on predicted values.

Maybe (probably) there is some context I'm missing, but these give me considerably different answers. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

### make data
set.seed(1)
df <- mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(
    random = rnorm(nrow(.), 1, 2),
    pred = mpg + random,
  )

### have a look
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(pred, mpg)) +
  geom_abline() +
  geom_point()

### method 1
observed_means <- mean(df$mpg)
predicted_means <- mean(df$pred)
calibration_in_large <- observed_means - predicted_means

calibration_in_large

# method 2
cal_mod <- lm(mpg ~ pred, df)
cal_mod
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I receieved an answer on Twitter from Gary Collins -

In 'method 2' you need to put pred as an offset (see https://sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0895435615005818) so your call in R should be

cal_mod <- lm(mpg ~ offset(pred), df)

and the estimate will agree with 'Method 1'